# Programmatically renew Windows 8 developer license?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to set up some automated testing against a Windows Store application. The big problem I see is that this will be setup a server we'd rather not touch and it just magically keep on building and running tests. This is a problem because Windows Store apps require a developer license to build or do anything with(like side-loading). And developer licenses must be renewed every 30 days.

Is there a programmatic way of renewing a developer license or some way to side-step this issue? I'd really rather not have to worry about logging into the build server every 30 days to renew the license

Comment: I dug into the cmdlet in Powershell for doing this, which uses .Net. Unfortunately, the cmdlet is basically a wrapper around the native DLL `WSClient.dll` .. so reverse engineering how this happens isn't easy

Comment: You're not the only person asking this question. I had someone else ask me this exact same thing in person just yesterday. It's too bad that there isn't a better story for this, or at least that it isn't well-known.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest setting up a remote connection to the machine. 
You could also try building a virtual macro application that allows running the powershell command that WPCoder suggested. You could try recording the steps you need to take in order to renew your license and try to run it on a certain day in every month (this can be done easily via VS2010 / 2012).

I hope this helps!
Good luck!

Comment: This sounds like the only way to do it. Just sucks that UI automation is required for such a brain-dead simple thing